# Flask app runs fine locally, throws 500 on Heroku (on some routes) & no logs

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a Flask app that runs fine locally. I pushed it to this Heroku URL:
https://secret-sierra-6425.herokuapp.com/

And the landing page works, which means the '/' route code works.
But when I try to access other resources, it throws a 500 error and I don't see anything useful in the logs:

```
2015-04-06T08:17:29.687713+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-06 08:17:29 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2015-04-06T08:17:30.397309+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-06 08:17:30 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
2015-04-06T08:17:30.484520+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-06 08:17:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2015-04-06T08:17:30.398009+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-06 08:17:30 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:18230 (3)
2015-04-06T08:17:30.398107+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-06 08:17:30 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2015-04-06T08:17:30.407696+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-04-06 08:17:30 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2015-04-06T08:17:30.682319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-06T08:17:30.618107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-04-06T08:18:23.485060+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=secret-sierra-6425.herokuapp.com request_id=cbdfada9-8b28-4150-a7c0-eddc458658d9 fwd="23.252.53.59" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=186
2015-04-06T08:18:35.630070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/messages" host=secret-sierra-6425.herokuapp.com request_id=aaecbfbd-57b5-49eb-aee0-ad450ba67e36 fwd="23.252.53.59" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=456
```

This is the code to start my app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True #Only for development, not prod
    app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    app.run()
```

Procfile:

```
web:    gunicorn mailr:app --log-file=-
worker: python worker.py
```

My application uses redis queue as well. I've added the RedisToGo addon. Still no luck.

Can anyone help me find a way to display the logs so that I can debug what's going wrong?
\

EDIT:

Also tried changing the start to this, but still no luck:

```
app.debug = True #Only for development, not prod
file_handler = StreamHandler()
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set the desired logging level here
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The code for logging should have been out of **main**